Google Signin Api Exception Developer Error
I developed the app using Flutter and integrated it with Firebase. I've added the SHA1 and SHA256 keys for both debug, release, and Google Play Console app signing to Firebase. These SHA keys were also automatically generated in the Google Cloud console. Google Sign-In works flawlessly on iOS, but on Android, after publishing to the Play Store, the sign-in works on some devices but fails on others with the following error:
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10, null, null).
I'm attaching a few screenshots as well.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I've added the SHA1 and SHA256 keys for both debug, release, and Google Play Console app signing to Firebase.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Does this answer help?
